# How do I save my game in Tokyo Jungle?

Tags: tokyo-jungle

Tokyo Jungle has (at least) two hints at a save system:

1. The menu screen has a "Continue" item
2. When quitting, it asks "Quit without saving?"

But, I can't figure out how to actually save the game! How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in the digital instruction booklet that can be accessed from the XMB while the game is running.

You can save the game from a nest. After aquiring a nest, which requires you to claim a territory by "marking" in 4 locations, you can **go to the nest and select the "Exit" option** (square button).

The game will then exit. Next time you start the game, the "Continue" menu item will be available.

*(The nest is related to mating, but mating is not required in order to save the game.)*

Answer (score 1):

> To save, the player must first take over a territory by tediously
>   marking predetermined spots and then finding a mate, both of which get
>   extremely tedious after a while.
>
> Once you find a nest and mate, you may save your game. Doing so,
>   however, sends you straight back to the title screen for no real
>   reason, especially seeing as the game does not allow saves across
>   different animals.